# Will two indexes in mysql be counterproductive?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes

I have a table 'xyz' in Mysql with 'id' as primary key.

'id' is by default index as it is a primary key. And 'score' is another column which is marked as index.

I want to sort my table w.r.t. the score, thus it is added as an index.

Will 'id' as also an index be counterproductive to 'score' for the below query?

```
SELECT * from xyz ORDER BY score DESC;
```

For the above query, which index is being used, id or score?

Comment: it will not be counterproductive. Look at the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858844/does-mysql-use-index-for-sorting

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.