# MySQL Performance: Ordering by content of joined tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing, denormalization

Is there a way to improve performance when ordering queries based on a dynamic subset of a larger table?

For reference, I have two tables:

- **products** - contains details about products, including names, prices, etc.
- **inventory_items** - contains the current inventory levels for various products from multiple vendors.

A common query might be something like:

```
select (columns)
from inventory_items ii
left join products p on ii.product_id = p.id
where ii.vendor_id = 123
order by p.name
limit 100
```

So there might be 50k rows we're looking at from inventory_items, which might be linked to 45k rows from the products table. (A left join is necessary in our case since we don't always have product data for everything in a vendor's inventory.)

This is relatively slow and hard to index: the query uses the primary key (id) of the products table for the join, and I don't think there's a useful index I could add to that table to improve performance when sorting by a different column in that table (such as the product name). A single product "has many" inventory items, so I can't just add an inventory_id to the products table.

I am currently considering denormalizing the table, either by adding the columns I need to the inventory_items table, or by creating a new table for compiled reports. That way I could add indexes to the inventory_items table such as (vendor_id, name) which would help improve performance when sorting by the name.

Is there a better option here than denormalization? Caching is difficult because there are about a dozen different fields each report could be sorted by, results need to be paginated, and there are various types of filters/searches that users can apply to the results.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to get your own explain plan from a query before and after creating indexes. An index on any column used in a join will help, plus others for columns used in the where clause. An index on p.name might speed up the sorting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858844/does-mysql-use-index-for-sorting#6858907

Answer (score 0):

```
inventory_items needs INDEX(vendor_id)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to product documentation (e.g.) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-index-use

> In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause and avoid the extra sorting involved in performing a filesort operation.
>
> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause.

An index can be used in sorting, and if that is true then sorting performance will be improved.

So, in your example, an index on `p.name` might improve sorting performance, however, the only way to know which indexes are being used, and when they are used, is to get an explain plan.